# plug in phoenix controller

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm writing a sample app to Phoenix framework.
my authenticate.ex:

```
defmodule Myapp.Plug.Authenticate do
  import Plug.Conn
  import Myapp.Router.Helpers
  import Phoenix.Controller

  def init(default), do: default

  def call(conn, default) do
    current_user = get_session(conn, :current_user)
    if current_user do
      assign(conn, :current_user, current_user)
    else
      conn
        |> put_flash(:error, 'You need to be signed in to view this page')
        |> redirect(to: session_path(conn, :new))
    end
  end
end
```

there is a controller in which I do not require authentication for a single action:

```
defmodule Myapp.SharedLinkController do
  use Myapp.Web, :controller
  alias Myapp.SharedLink

  plug Myapp.Plug.Authenticate when action in [:new, :create]

...

end
```

it works, but the problem is that there is a menu display depends on whether the user is authorized or not:

```
<%= if Map.has_key?(@conn.assigns, :current_user) do %>
  <li>first</li>
<% else %>
  <li>second</li>
<% end %>
```

and it turns out that on the page action, which I do not require authentication, I get that a user is not authorized, even when it is authorized. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: "I get that a user is not authorized" you mean you get the flash and redirect or you get the wrong menu?

Comment: @Dogbert, I get the wrong menu

Comment: What is the value of `@conn.assigns[:current_user]` when you're logged out? Try adding `<%= inspect @conn.assigns[:current_user] %>` and seeing the output.

Comment: Does this work: `<%= if assigns[:current_user] do %>`?

Comment: No, I get the wrong menu on all pages

Comment: You should invoke **halt/1** in call function after redirect to prevent further plugs downstream from being invoked. Also in your template you should be able to invoke `<%= if @current_user do %>` to check if user is authenticated or not. HIH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the code in two steps - first attempting to authenticate the user, loading from the database and assigning to the connection - you can always run this one, and simply assign `nil`, a special guest user or nothing, whatever you prefer. The second would be enforcing the user is authenticated based on the assigns in the connection - this one would run only where you need to - like the plug you currently have.

Comment: Do I understand you, I have to do two "the authenticate" - a "soft" option, which aims to assign the current user or guest, and the second option - a "hard", which redirects to the login page if the user is not authorized ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.